# MAUI Label data binding raises NullReferenceException but TextCell works

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a pretty simple MVVM App, inside *DataTemplate* of a *ListView*, there is a *Label* control binds to my *Label* property (a string).

```xml
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I starts the app, a NullReferenceException is throw:

[image: Screen shot of the exception]

Even if I don't use any binding, the app still throws NullReferenceException:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Text="SomeText" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

But if I use *TextCell* to replace *Label*, everything is fine: the app starts and the binding is working.

```xml
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTemplates` in a `ListView` should always use a `Cell`, so the `NullReferenceException` you're seeing has nothing to do with the `Label` or it's binding probably.

Change your code to this:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```